# Como podria bloquear teclado y raton usando python 3.9?

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un programa en python que me gustaria que bloqueara el uso de teclado y raton durante su ejecucion.
Me parecio ver que pyHook podria hacer algo parecido, pero no parece que sea compatible con python 3.9 por lo que he llegado a leer.  Me gustaria saber si esto es asi o si por el contrario mi informacion es incorrecta. Ademas de con pyHook hay alguna otra libreria que permita hacer lo que necesito?
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Quieres bloquearlo sólo para tu aplicación o para todo el PC?

Comment: Pues para todo el pc estaria bien, porque estoy usando la libreria pyautogui para hacer  haciendo clicks de raton,  e insercion de texto por teclado.  Por ese motivo  si el usuario toca el raton o el teclado el programa ya deja de funcionar correctamente.  Lo ideal seria que aunq muevan el raton o el teclado no afecte,  por eso pense en bloquearlos